# Auto-GPT's "Summarizing chunk" always fails

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, autogpt

When the retrieved document is too long, "Summarizing chunk" is used, but every time Auto-GPT tries "Summarizing chunk", it fails and I get the following error.

```
Text length: 63750 characters
Adding chunk 1 / 3 to memory
Summarizing chunk 1 / 3 of length 27468 characters, or 8102 tokens
SYSTEM:  Command browse_website returned: Error: This model's maximum context length is 4097 tokens. However, your messages resulted in 8102 tokens. Please reduce the length of the messages.
```

Usually, the "Summarizing chunk" is done many times like

1/3 to memory,2/3 to memory,3/3 to memory,

and then sent to chatgpt, but this does not work.

Which settings should I review?
Auto-GPT's Version is 0.2.2

I just mentioned the above settings in this question but still if more code is required then tell me I'll update my question with that information. Thank you

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?